# How should I expose a "bidirectional" interface in WinRT with C#

Tags: c#, .net, interface, windows-runtime

So, I have a very simple C#/.Net interface. Now, I need to expose this interface to WinRT though. So, at the moment I have these interfaces

```
//.Net (in the `Common` namespace)
public interface IWriter
{
  void Write(string text);
}

//WinRT (in the `WinRT` namespace)
public interface IWriter
{
  void Write(string text);
}
```

I would've though I could just do `IWriter : Common.IWriter` but apparently that won't work, despite using WinRT friendly types. So, now I'm writing a two-way wrapper that implements both:

```
//WinRT
internal class WriterWrapper : Common.IWriter, IWriter
{
  Common.IWriter CommonWriter;
  IWriter WinRTWriter;
  public WriterWrapper(IWriter writer)
  {
    WinRTWriter=writer;
  }
  public WriterWrapper(Common.IWriter writer)
  {
    CommonWriter=writer;
  }
  void Common.IWriter.Write(string text)
  {
    if(WinRTWriter == null)
    {
      CommonWriter.Write(text);
    }else{
      WinRTWriter.Write(text);
    }
  }
  void IWriter.Write(string text)
  {
    ((Common.IWriter)this).Write(text);
  }
}
```

This is quite ugly and tedious though. Also, using it where I need to leads to an "infinite" object graph.

I require this interface because I have a .Net class like this:

```
//.Net (`Common` namespace)
public class Config
{
  public IWriter Writer{get;set;}
}
```

My best guess at exposing this property to WinRT is to wrap this object:

```
//WinRT
public class Config
{
  Common.Config CommonConfig;
  public Config()
  {
    CommonConfig=new Common.Config();
  }
  public IWriter Writer
  {
    get
    {
      return new WriterWrapper(CommonConfig.Writer);
    }
    set
    {
      CommonConfig.Writer=new WriterWrapper(value);
    }
  }
}
```

So, for every access someone makes to `WinRT.Config.Writer` a new object is created and never released until the Config object goes out of scope.

How can I prevent this and is there an overall better way of doing this?

Comment: It isn't clear to me why you wouldn't just store the object you create and use it again later.